# Exception on running custom cron groups

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, windows

For some reason when I run custom cron groups I get the following error (note this is using IIS on Windows which is not officially supported).

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group=custom
```

> Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly

and

> `start /B "magento background task" C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\v7.0\php.exe "c:\dev\bin/magento" cron:run
>
>   --group=custom --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1 2>&1`

If I run the cron tasks which are part of this group as the default group I do not get this error.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by adding

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group=custom --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1
```

Found this through [this blog](https://belvg.com/blog/how-it-works-cron-job-in-magento-2.html)

> As you can see, this command is running for index group tasks and the
>   flag –bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1 means that any child
>   process has not been created, otherwise there could happen that each
>   command creates Crons for all the groups and the process would enter
>   an infinite loop.